# extract data from XML files - R

Tags: r, xml

I'm new to extracting data from XML file. I'm trying to process the following an XML file using R XML packages. The information I want is in the attribute values.

I encounter two difficulties:

1. some attribute values exist in one node, but not in another node. For example, "DRP" has the information in the second  but not in the first
2. some attributes has multiple values for an individual and i don't know how to link them to that individual. For example, "EmpHs" has multiple records for an individual (identified by indvlPK).

Ideally I want the output data has the structure similar to the following:

| lastNm | firstNm | indvlPK | fromDt | orgNm | hasCustComp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GIGAX | JEFFREY | 2783477 | 03/2004 | GATEWAY FINANCIAL ADVISORS, INC |  |
| GIGAX | JEFFREY | 2783477 | 03/2004 | GFA IN |  |
| GIGAX | JEFFREY | 2783477 | 01/2007 | UNITED FIRST |  |
| HINSON | BRIAN | 2783737 | 07/1996 | LINCOLN FINANCIAL ADVISORS CORPORATION | Y |
| HINSON | BRIAN | 2783737 | 07/1996 | FIRST FINANCIAL GROUP | Y |

Is there any way I can parse the data correctly? Thanks!

The code I used but didn't give me what I want:

```
doc <- "Test.xml"
ind <- xmlParse(doc)
xmltop = xmlRoot(ind)

temp1 <- data.frame(unlist(getNodeSet(xmltop,"//Info/@lastNm")))
temp2 <- data.frame(unlist(getNodeSet(xmltop,"//Info/@firstNm")))
temp3 <- data.frame(unlist(getNodeSet(xmltop,"//Info/@indvlPK")))
temp4 <- data.frame(unlist(getNodeSet(xmltop,"//EmpHs/@fromDt")))
temp5 <- data.frame(unlist(getNodeSet(xmltop,"//DRP/@hasCustComp")))
```

The data is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<IAPDIndividualReport GenOn="2021-03-29">
<Indvls>
<Indvl>
<Info lastNm="GIGAX" firstNm="JEFFREY" midNm="W" indvlPK="2783477" actvAGReg="Y" link="https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/individual/summary/2783477"/>
<OthrNms/>
<CrntEmps>
<CrntEmp orgNm="CAMBRIDGE INVESTMENT RESEARCH ADVISORS, INC." orgPK="134139" str1="1776 PLEASANT PLAIN RD." city="FAIRFIELD" state="IA" cntry="United States" postlCd="52556-8757">
<CrntRgstns>
<CrntRgstn regAuth="MO" regCat="RA" st="APPROVED" stDt="2010-09-09"/>
</CrntRgstns>
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc city="O&apos;FALLON" state="MO" cntry="United States"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</CrntEmp>
</CrntEmps>
<Exms>
<Exm exmCd="S63" exmNm="Uniform Securities Agent State Law Examination" exmDt="1996-08-20"/>
<Exm exmCd="S65" exmNm="Uniform Investment Adviser Law Examination" exmDt="1999-12-21"/>
</Exms>
<Dsgntns/>
<PrevRgstns>
<PrevRgstn orgNm="WOODBURY FINANCIAL SERVICES, INC." orgPK="421" regBeginDt="2009-01-05" regEndDt="2009-12-03">
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc city="OFALLON" state="MO"/>
<BrnchOfLoc city="OFALLON" state="MO"/>
<BrnchOfLoc city="DUBLIN" state="CA"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</PrevRgstn>
<PrevRgstn orgNm="FSC SECURITIES CORPORATION" orgPK="7461" regBeginDt="2004-10-29" regEndDt="2008-12-01">
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc city="O&apos;FALLON" state="MO"/>
<BrnchOfLoc city="ST. PETERS" state="MO"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</PrevRgstn>
<PrevRgstn orgNm="GATEWAY FINANCIAL ADVISORS, INC." orgPK="115025" regBeginDt="2004-11-11" regEndDt="2006-10-11">
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc city="ST. PETERS" state="MO"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</PrevRgstn>
</PrevRgstns>
<EmpHss>
<EmpHs fromDt="03/2004" orgNm="GATEWAY FINANCIAL ADVISORS, INC" city="OFALLON" state="MO"/>
<EmpHs fromDt="03/2004" orgNm="GFA INC" city="OFALLON" state="MO"/>
<EmpHs fromDt="01/2007" orgNm="UNITED FIRST" city="OFALLON" state="MO"/>
<EmpHs fromDt="09/2010" orgNm="CAMBRIDGE INVESTMENT RESEARCH ADVISORS, INC" city="FAIRFIELD" state="IA"/>
<EmpHs fromDt="09/2010" orgNm="CAMBRIDGE INVESTMENT RESEARCH, INC" city="FAIRFIELD" state="IA"/>
</EmpHss>
<OthrBuss>
<OthrBus desc="1)STONEBRIDGE WEALTH MANAGEMENT GROUP, 728 HAWK RUN DR, O&apos;FALLON, MO, 3/2008 AS INDEPENDENT INSURANCE AGENT FOR VARIOUS INDEPENDENT INSURANCE COMPANIES. INV REL - 40/MO - 20/TRADING.    2)UNITED FIRST FINANCIAL MORTGAGE SOFTWARE SALES. START 6/1/07, 10 HOURS PER MONTH, 5 DURING TRADING HOURS. NO OWNERSHIP INTEREST.     3)MORTGAGE STOP INC., 728 HAWK RUN DR., OFALLON, MO 63368. LOAN OFFICER PROCESSING LOAN APPS FOR CLIENTS. START 6/1/2002, 25 HOURS PER MONTH, 10 DURING TRADING HOURS. NO OWNERSHIP.     4)CIRA, 1776 PLEASANT PLAIN RD, FAIRFIELD, IA, AS ADVISORY REP OF A RIA. INV REL - 40 HR/WK - 40/TRADING. SEE EMPLOYMENT HISTORY FOR START DATE.    5) THE MORTGAGE SHOP, 355 MID RIVERS MALL DRIVE, STE E, ST. PETERS, MO 63376. MORTGAGE ORIGINATOR SINCE 01/01/99. NOT INVESTMENT RELATED. WORKS 60 HOURS PER MONTH, 20 OF WHICH ARE DURING TRADING HOURS.    6.365 PROPERTIES LLC, O&apos;FALLON, MO, 8/2018 AS OWNER OF LLC THAT BUYS, SELLS, &amp; HOLDS REAL ESTATE. NIR - 20/MO - 0/TRADING.    7. BEST OFFER HOMES, LLC, 728 HAWK RUN DRIVE, O&apos;FALLON, MO, REAL ESTATE SALES/MORTGAGE ORIGINATION/ ACCOUNTING/FINANCIAL ACTIVITIES, 06/16/20, NIR, 20/MO- 0/TRADING    8. GIGAX WEALTH MANAGEMENT, 728 HAWK RUN DRIVE, OFALLON, MO, INDEPENDENT INSURANCE AGENT FOR VARIOUS INDEPENDENT INSURANCE COMPANIES,11/23/20, INV REL, 10 HR/WK- 10 TRADING HR."/>
</OthrBuss>
<DRPs/>
</Indvl>
<Indvl>
<Info lastNm="HINSON" firstNm="BRIAN" midNm="TROY" indvlPK="2783737" actvAGReg="Y" link="https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/individual/summary/2783737"/>
<OthrNms/>
<CrntEmps>
<CrntEmp orgNm="BRIDGEWORTH WEALTH MANAGEMENT" orgPK="164100" str1="101 25TH STREET NORTH" city="BIRMINGHAM" state="AL" cntry="United States" postlCd="35203">
<CrntRgstns>
<CrntRgstn regAuth="AL" regCat="RA" st="APPROVED" stDt="2015-05-12"/>
<CrntRgstn regAuth="TX" regCat="RA" st="APPROVED_RES" stDt="2015-05-01"/>
</CrntRgstns>
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc str1="400 MERIDIAN STREET" str2="SUITE 200" city="HUNTSVILLE" state="AL" cntry="United States" postlCd="35801"/>
<BrnchOfLoc str1="101 25TH STREET NORTH" city="BIRMINGHAM" state="AL" cntry="United States" postlCd="35203"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</CrntEmp>
</CrntEmps>
<Exms>
<Exm exmCd="S63" exmNm="Uniform Securities Agent State Law Examination" exmDt="1996-10-11"/>
</Exms>
<Dsgntns>
<Dsgntn dsgntnNm="Certified Financial Planner"/>
<Dsgntn dsgntnNm="Chartered Financial Consultant"/>
<Dsgntn dsgntnNm="Personal Financial Specialist"/>
</Dsgntns>
<PrevRgstns>
<PrevRgstn orgNm="LINCOLN FINANCIAL ADVISORS CORPORATION" orgPK="3978" regBeginDt="2000-04-25" regEndDt="2015-05-11">
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc city="HUNTSVILLE" state="AL"/>
<BrnchOfLoc city="HUNTSVILLE" state="AL"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</PrevRgstn>
</PrevRgstns>
<EmpHss>
<EmpHs fromDt="04/2015" orgNm="BRIDGEWORTH, LLC" city="HUNTSVILLE" state="AL"/>
<EmpHs fromDt="07/1996" toDt="04/2015" orgNm="LINCOLN FINANCIAL ADVISORS CORPORATION" city="HUNTSVILLE" state="AL"/>
<EmpHs fromDt="07/1996" toDt="04/2015" orgNm="FIRST FINANCIAL GROUP" city="BIRMINGHAM" state="AL"/>
<EmpHs fromDt="04/2015" orgNm="LPL FINANCIAL LLC" city="HUNTSVILLE" state="AL"/>
</EmpHss>
<OthrBuss>
<OthrBus desc="1) 04/30/2015: BRIDGEWORTH FINANCIAL, LLC - DBA FOR LPL BUSINESS (ENTITY FOR LPL BUSINESS) - INV REL - AT REPORTED BUSINESS LOCATIONS - START 01/01/2015 - 1% OF TIME SPENT      2) 04/30/2015: BRIDGEWORTH, LLC - INV REL - AT REPORTED BUSINESS LOCATION(S) - REGISTERED INVESTMENT ADVISOR HYBRID - START 01/2015 - 99% OF TIME SPENT.      3) 5/11/2015: NO BUSINESS NAME - INVESTMENT RELATED - AT REPORTED BUSINESS LOCATION(S) - NON-VARIABLE INSURANCE - STARTED 4/1/2015 - TIME SPENT 1% - LINES OF INSURANCE INCLUDE TERM, WHOLE, UNIVERSAL, LTC, DISABILITY.        4) 6/2/2017 - Bridgeworth Financial - Investment Related - At Reported Business Location(s) - DBA for LPL Business (entity for LPL business) - Started 04/30/2015 - 5 Hours Per Month/3 Hours During Securities Trading.    5) 5/8/2018 - Foster Properties Ltd - Not Investment Related - Home Based - Other-Family Business - Started 12/22/1997 - 1 Hours Per Month/0 Hours During Securities Trading - Handle the majority of business matters for this family business."/>
</OthrBuss>
<DRPs>
<DRP hasRegAction="N" hasCriminal="N" hasBankrupt="N" hasCivilJudc="N" hasBond="N" hasJudgment="N" hasInvstgn="N" hasCustComp="Y" hasTermination="N"/>
</DRPs>
</Indvl>
</Indvls>
</IAPDIndividualReport>
```